# Flyback Mosfet Overcurrent Problem

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, high-voltage, ozone

I am building a power supply for an ozone generator. It is a simple design, I will add feedback loops later. But for now I am trying to produce 4KV output(40W). But there is a problem with current. Micro-Cap simulations show that current is too much. Goes around 4 - 10 amps. If I put a multiplier to seconder it goes even higher like 20amps. What is the reason. How can I fix it? [image: question]

Comment: 100k load seems too much - increase the resistor value - an ozone generator will only use microamps. Try 100Meg. What frequency are you driving it at?

Comment: @KevinWhite Thanks for answer I will try 50kHz - 100kHz experimenting sir.

Comment: R8 is probably too low. Don't forget you require the inductive kick since it is a flyback converter. You don't want to absorb it in the snubber.

Comment: @KevinWhite Yes. Thanks. Actually I am simulating it with K=1 I didn't calculated it properly. Lack or miscalculated snubber circuit can be the reason of overcurrent ?

Answer (score 2):

Those 4 series diodes need 1MegOhm resistors across them, to ensure the reverse voltages are somewhat equalized. Or try 2.2 Megohm, or 4.7MegOhm.

Because of the high voltages, you should use discrete leaded  1/2 watt resistors.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Okey I will use them but I thought that since output voltage in the picture is only 2KV, 4KV diodes should be enough for rectifying without resistors you mention about. Do you have an idea about overcurrent on mosfet. Should I look for snubber circuit analysis or it is normal for this type of circuit.